# How can I retrieve Notifications list of status bar programmatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

How can I retrieve Notification list of status bar programmatically on android?

I found some ways like `NotificationListenerService`, but I would be happy to know any methods or apis that I can retrieve every `StatusBarNotification` s in one method call.

```
public List<StatusBarNotification> getNotifications()
{
    //...
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to comment I found some way. I'll post it later when I am finished, for further users.

Comment: what's stopping you from using that service and implementing this method yourself?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't know how to communicate between two Services.. :(

Comment: then why aren't you asking about that instead

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks! I 'll try that.

Comment: I am finished and I'll post here after debugging